# How can i Get Second Page's Response in AWS?

Tags: web-services, api, rest, webservice-client

I am new to AWS. I got the  AWS response like this.

```
<Items>
<Request>
  <IsValid>True</IsValid>
  <ItemSearchRequest>
    <Brand>Levi's</Brand>
    <Keywords>Men</Keywords>
    <ResponseGroup>Large</ResponseGroup>
    <SearchIndex>Apparel</SearchIndex>
  </ItemSearchRequest>
</Request>
*<TotalResults>282</TotalResults>
<TotalPages>29</TotalPages>*
 ***<Item>***
  <ASIN>B004A7YLN6</ASIN>
  <DetailPageURL>http://www.amazon.com/Levis-Extra-Capacity-Slimfold-Wallet/dp/B004A7YLN6%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIETT7RP2RAFF4UUQ%26tag%3Dws%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB004A7YLN6</DetailPageURL>
  <SmallImage>
    <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51z7oqZYgoL._SL75_.jpg</URL>
    <Height Units="pixels">71</Height>
    <Width Units="pixels">75</Width>
  </SmallImage>
  <MediumImage>
    <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51z7oqZYgoL._SL160_.jpg</URL>
    <Height Units="pixels">152</Height>
    <Width Units="pixels">160</Width>
  </MediumImage>
   <ItemAttributes>
    <Binding>Apparel</Binding>
    <Brand>Levi's</Brand>
    <Department>mens</Department>
    <FabricType>100% Genuine Leather</FabricType>
    <Feature>Natural fold construction</Feature>
    <Feature>9 Credit card pockets</Feature>
    <Feature>Top entry mesh ID window pocket</Feature>
    </ItemAttributes>
    </Item>
     <Items>
```

Now, I am getting Ten Items per page. I need to get the response of the second Page.
How can i get the response of the second Page. here total page is 29.
Please let me know, if you need more information. I am using REST in Asp.net applicatioon.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this has little to do with AWS and is more about the application you are talking to.  In AWS with S3 for example, you get a `isTruncated` flag with the results indicating that you can request further results (by sending a "start from" type of parameter).  The application you are calling needs to provide you with some way of doing this.  If the application is one you have writted yourself, you need to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The `ItemPage` parameter enables you to return a specified page of results. The maximum ItemPage number that can be returned is 10 (5 if you use 'All' as `SearchIndex`).

- See Amazon documentation for more information: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html
- For your information Amazon ECS PHP Library Version 1.3 includes a page() function. Note that the library is no longer maintained: https://github.com/Exeu/Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library