# Zend API Amazon: How do I get more than 10 items?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api, zend-framework

I trying to develop a php page that shows all items from category "Videogames" with a Keywords, only I can show the first 10 item, but total results are 254 items.
Can anybody help me? Best,

```
$query  = new ZendService\Amazon\Query($appId, 'ES', $secretKey);
$query->Category($categoria_buscar)->Keywords($keywords_buscar)->AssociateTag($tag)->ResponseGroup('Medium,SalesRank,OfferSummary')->Sort($orden_buscar)->MinimumPrice('no');
$result = $query->search();

foreach($result as $item):?>
    <div class="item">
    <?php echo "Artículo ->".($result->key()+1)."<br />";?>
    <a href="<?php echo $item->DetailPageURL ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $item->Title?></a>
    <?php 
        if(isset($item->SalesRank)) echo "<br />Ranking de ventas: ".$item->SalesRank;
        if(isset($item->Manufacturer)) echo "<br />Fabricante: ".$item->Manufacturer;
        if(isset($item->Platform)) echo "<br />Plataforma: ".$item->Platform;
    ?>
  <br /><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Zend framework for Amazon you can request any page results from 1 to 10 using the `Page()` function.

For example in your case:

```
$page_num=2;

$query->Category($categoria_buscar)->Keywords($keywords_buscar)->AssociateTag($tag)->ResponseGroup('Medium,SalesRank,OfferSummary')->Sort($orden_buscar)->MinimumPrice('no')->Page($page_num);
```

Note that if you use 'All' as a Category the max page is 5.

**Other Resources**

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html
- [How can i Get Second Page's Response in AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363032/how-can-i-get-second-pages-response-in-aws/19743465#19743465)